# How to check if the element is present in the dom and add some style to another element in dom using react?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

i want to check if an element is present in the dom and add style to another element in the dom using react.
What i am trying to do?
i have a popup and a button displayed in same page. so when the button is present i want to add a space of 16px between the popup and button.
below is the snippet,

```
const Root = ()  => {
    <PopupContextProvider>
        <App/>
    </PopupContextProvider/>
}

function App() {
    return (
        <Items/>
        <Drawer/>
    );
}

function Items() {
    const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = React.useState(openByDefault); 
    const availableItems = 10;
    useItemsTrigger(isOpen, availableItems);
}
        
function Drawer() {
    return (
        <DrawerButton/> //here is where the DrawerButton is called
    );
}


function DrawerButton({ onClick, active, disabled }: Props) { 
    return (
        <ButtonElement //this is the button
            onClick={onClick}
            data-testid="drawer-button"
        />
    );
}

const ButtonElement = styled(IconButton)`
    position: fixed;
    left: ${-toggleWidthPx - toggleGutterPx}px;
    bottom: ${toggleGutterPx}px;
    width: ${toggleWidthPx}px;
    height: ${toggleWidthPx}px;
    padding: 0;
    & > svg {
        margin: 0;
    }
`;


interface ContextProps {
    triggerForItems: (availableItems: number) => void;
    triggerForProducts: (availableProducts: number) => void;
}

const popupContext = React.createContext<ContextProps>({
    triggerForItems: (availableItems: number) => {},
    triggerForProducts: (availableProducts: number) => {}, 
});

const usePopupContext = () => React.useContext(popupContext);

export const PopupContextProvider = ({ children }: any) => {
    const [showForItems, setShowForItems] = React.useState(false);
    const [showForProducts, setShowForProducts] = React.useState(false);

    const dismiss = () => {
        if (showForItems) {
            sessionStorage.setItem(itemsPopupId, 'dismissed');
            setShowForItems(false);
        }
        if (showForProducts) {
            sessionStorage.setItem(mobileUsersPopupId, 'dismissed');
            setShowForProducts(false);
        }
    };

    const isDismissed = (dialogId: string) => {
        sessionStorage.getItem(dialogId) === 'dismissed';

    const context = {
        triggerForItems: (availableItems: number) => {
            if (!isDismissed(itemsPopupId) && availableItems <= limit)   {
                setShowForItems(true);
            } else if (availableitems > limit) {
                setShowForItems(false);
            }
        },
        triggerForProducts: (availableProducts: number) => {
            if (!isDismissed(productsPopupId) && availableProducts <= limit) {                
                setShowForProducts(true);
            } else if (availableProducts > limit) {
                setShowForProducts(false);
            }
        },
    };

    return (
        <popupContext.Provider value={context}>
            {children}
            {(showForSiteShares || showForMobileUsers) && (
                <Popup onHide={dismiss} />
            )}
        </popupContext.Provider>
    );
};


export function useProductsTrigger(
    enabled: boolean,
    availableProducts: number
) {
    const { triggerForProducts } = usePopupContext();
    React.useEffect(() => {
        if (enabled) {
            triggerForProducts(availableProducts);
        }
    }, [enabled, availableProducts, triggerForProducts]);
}

export function useItemsTrigger(
    enabled: boolean,
    availableItems: number 
) {
    const { triggerForItems } = usePopupContext();
    React.useEffect(() => {
    if (enabled) {
        triggerForItems(availableItems);
    }
}, [enabled, availableItems, triggerForItems]);




export function Popup() { //this is the popup
    return (
        <Dialog>
            <Body>
                <span>Title</span>
                <Description/>
            </Body>
            <Actions>
                <span> Hide</span>
            </Actions>
        </Dialog>
    );
```

}

How can i check if the button (ButtonElement) is present in DOM and add margin-left to popup (Dialog).

i can add id to ButtonElement and check if the element is present. but do i add style to Popup if element is present?

Also can i use ref instead of adding id to ButtonElement? If so how to do it?

Or is there any other better way to do this?

could someone help me solve this. thanks.

Comment: Can you add snippet where you're rendering Button and Popup.

Comment: Popup will be visible throughout the application any view provided by context when somecondition met say count is 0. so when count is 0 in some component that triggers showing popup and will be visible in any page of application unless hide button clicked. and ButtonElement is seen only in one page.

Comment: Are the button's and popup's elements adjacent elements in the DOM when both present?

Comment: not adjacent elements. within div with clssname App i have buttonelement with all other elements of that page and next to div with classname app i have popup (Dialog)

Comment: Hm, in that case it might be a bit harder to do it with CSS only. Can you share a component which uses both Button and Popup? (I assume they're together part of a parent component).

Comment: I have the popup from the context which is wraped arount app component.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should [lift the state up](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html).

The source of truth should live in your state, not the DOM.

The popup is rendered due to some condition, that condition should be stored in state and then shared with the rest of the application. You can use the [Context API](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html) to do so.

Then in your button component you can query that state and adjust the style accordingly.

So this setup should look something like this:

```
const PopupContext = createContext()

const App() {
   const [popupVisible, setPopoupVisible] = useState(false)
   
   <PopupContext.Provider value={{ popupVisible, setPopupVisible }}>
    /* the rest of you application code, any component can set or use the context values */
    
   </PopupContext.Provider>
}

const DrawerButton() {
   const { popupVisible } = useContext(PopupContext)
   return ... // draw button with customized styles
 
}
```

Make sure that the popup is shown if and only if the `popupVisible` state is true.

EDIT (OP updated the question):

You can add the visibility state to your context -

```
interface ContextProps {
    triggerForItems: (availableItems: number) => void;
    triggerForProducts: (availableProducts: number) => void;
    isPopupVisible: boolean;
}


const context = {
    isPopupVisible: showForItems || showForProducts,
    triggerForItems: (availableItems: number) => {
        if (!isDismissed(itemsPopupId) && availableItems <= limit)   {
            setShowForItems(true);
        } else if (availableitems > limit) {
            setShowForItems(false);
        }
    },
    triggerForProducts: (availableProducts: number) => {
        if (!isDismissed(productsPopupId) && availableProducts <= limit) {                
            setShowForProducts(true);
        } else if (availableProducts > limit) {
            setShowForProducts(false);
        }
    },
};
```

Comment: thanks this idea seems to be neat. but my context looks different. i shall edit my question to show the context code.

Comment: i have updated my question with the context and how it the popup is triggered to be shown. there is no state in context that i can access right now

Comment: could you please check the edited question. thanks.